# Making MacBook command-key the Emacs meta-key under VMware/Windows

Tags: macos, vmware, emacs, keyboard

I can configure emacs under OS X so that the key nearest the space bar (the key labeled <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>) is my Meta key by running

```
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
```

How can I configure the same key to be the emacs Meta-key when I run emacs under Windows, and Windows is itself running in VMware Fusion? For some reason even if I run the above line on Windows-VMware, my Meta key remains the Option key.

Answer (score 2):

To get Emacs on Windows to recognize something other than the <kbd>Alt</kbd> as the meta key is hard.

However, you can easily remap any keys on the Mac keyboard, including modifier keys, to be any other keys on the Windows keyboard via Fusion.  I have my <kbd>⌘</kbd> key mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows.  So one way to make the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key your meta key is to map <kbd>⌘</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

In Fusion 5, Select Virtual Machine -> Settings... -> Keyboard & Mouse. That will bring up a list of profiles you can select from, duplicate, and edit.  Hopefully it's obvious from there; if not, consult the built-in help by clicking on the question mark on the lower right of the Keyboard & Mouse panel.

Answer (score 0):

VMware (and Parallels and Windows in Boot Camp) use the Command key as the Windows key.

Can you map the Windows key to meta in emacs?